# I want to use apiwiki to put info in my bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

Here is my code:

```
bot.on('inline_query', async ctx => {

let query = ctx.inlineQuery.query;

let res = await axios.get(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=&{query}&limit=50`);
console.log(res.data);
})
```

why it doent work?

Answer (score 1):

first, your query is incorrect. instead `&{query}` type `${query}` like this:
`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=${query}&limit=50`

but it still wil not resolve it. now you will have to deal with CORS policy. to fix it, you shuld add `origin` to the query.

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=${query}&limit=50&origin=*`

end result:

```js
const query = 'test';

axios.get(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=${query}&limit=50&origin=*`).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
```